# write() on protected memory region does not trigger sigsegv, but standard access does

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'm trying to understand why calling a write on a memory protected region does not trigger a `sigsegv`. Consider the example:

```
void *map_addr;
unsigned long addr;

map_addr = (void *)mmap(NULL, 0x4000, PROT_READ_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
mprotect(map_addr, 0x4000, PROT_NONE);

addr = (unsigned long)map_addr;

// case 1:
*(volatile int*)(addr);  // sigsegv sent
// case 2:
write(STDOUT_FILENO, map_addr, size); // sigsegv NOT sent
```

Instead of sending a `sigsegv`, write in this instance returns `-1` and sets `errno=EFAULT`. Why does write have this behavior? I would imagine write would have attempted reading from the address, which creates the sigsegv fault but this is evidently not the case.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the standard where it requires sigsegv for undefined behaviour by access. And did you check the machine code? Did it execute? What does the debugger say?

Comment: @Olaf Case 1 executes and enteres the handler for SIGSEGV as expected. If I run Case 2, I do not enter the handler and the write simply returns -1 specifying `EFAULT` in errno, so there is no crash in case 2.

As for the reference, I just assumed and I/O on protected memory generated a sigsegv

Comment: @Olaf What standard? The linux standard?

Comment: There's no reason that the OP should need to provide a reference for the expected behavior.  That would be extra credit, if it were known, but is not needed for this to be a reasonable question.

Comment: The C standard. And I did not say "crash". That's not a standard term for good reasons.

Comment: @WayneConrad: What is the "expected behaviour" for _**undefined** behaviour_?

Comment: @Olaf What does the C standard have to do with SIGSEGV, Linux, or `write`? Not every question tagged `C` is about purely ISO standard C.

Comment: @Olaf if you look into the [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page, you see that SIGSEGV is defined for all invalid memory access. This is why I assumed write though send this signal

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: 1) So it is **guaranteed** to be emitted _under all circumstances_? 2) Did you check - as I wrote - the machine code, if it was not just optimised away?

Comment: this statement: `*(volatile int*)(addr);` did not write anything.  However it will cause a compiler to output a warning message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`write` is a system call, so the memory access happens in the kernel, not in your process. The kernel first checks whether the passed address is valid for the calling process, and if it isn't, it simply returns `EFAULT`.

(I don't know why it was designed to work this way, though.)

Comment: So in this case, `write` enters the kernel, which sees the calling address has `PROT_NONE` and considers it an `EFAULT`?

Comment: I fully agree, if you make that passed address *range*.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Yes, exactly.

Comment: One reason could be that it would be problematic to catch the signal in the kernel and raise the machine exception later for the application itself.

Comment: @Olaf: At least in Linux, the syscalls that return `-EFAULT` could just as well also cause a `SIGSEGV` to be raised for the calling thread; there is no need to let the hardware actually try to access the memory. However, then, there is a possibility of a signal storm deadlocky thing, if this were to occur in the signal handler -- and that is reason enough, I'd guess, for syscalls used to implement async-signal-safe functions to not to raise `SIGSEGV` nor `SIGBUS` signals (which, technically, can be caught; and outside of standard C is actually an useful method in certain strange cases).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I just speculated about **one** possible reason. Of course there can be others, more relevant. Depending on how that is handled internally, it can complicate the kernel code. NUMA architectures can add additional complications. Anyway, it is well documented behaviour and part of POSIX, so there is no use in further discussion.

Comment: @Olaf: True! I just wanted to extrapolate your comment, specifically to Linux and how it'd lead to other, quite severe problems.